# Error inserting data into a many to many join table with Entity Framework on SQL Server on ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, many-to-many, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to carry out an operation that inserts data into a many to many tables but I get the following error when I try :

> The property 'ComponentId' on entity type 'StaffComponent' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

But when I try it running in debug mode, it runs as expected. Here is my model and the controller below:

The models

StaffComponent Model

```
public class StaffComponent
{
    public string StaffId { get; set; }
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public Decimal ValueAmount { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StaffId")]
    public ApplicationUser Staff { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ComponentId")]
    public Component Component { get; set; }
}
```

Component Model

```
public class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name ="Calculation Type")]
    public Adding Addtype { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<StaffComponent> StaffComponents { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PaymentComponent> PaymentEntries{ get; set; }
}

public enum Adding
{
    Deduction=1,Addition=2
}
```

The Controller where I am trying to perform the insert operation

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult updatecomponents(StaffEntryUpdateModel postedData)
    {
        try
        {
            if (postedData.StaffComponents.Any())
            {
                ApplicationUser Staff = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == postedData.StaffId);

                if (Staff == null)
                {
                    return new JsonResult(new { Status = false, Message = "Unknown staff" });
                }

                db.StaffComponents.Where(se => se.StaffId == postedData.StaffId).Delete();
                IList<StaffComponent> newComponents = new List<StaffComponent>();
                foreach (var c in postedData.StaffComponents)
                {
                    newComponents.Add(new StaffComponent()
                        {
                            StaffId=c.StaffId,ComponentId=c.ComponentId,ValueAmount=c.ValueAmount
                        });
                }
                db.StaffComponents.AddRange(newComponents);

                int inserted = db.SaveChanges();

                return new JsonResult(new { Status = (inserted > 0) ? true : false, Message = inserted + " components updated for staff" });
            }
            else
            {
                return new JsonResult(new { Status = false, Message = "No component sent for update for staff" });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new JsonResult(new {Status=false,Message=e.Message.ToString() });
        }
    }
```

The relationship mapping is as follows

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<StaffComponent>()
            .HasKey(s => new { s.ComponentId, s.StaffId });

        builder.Entity<PaymentComponent>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.ComponentId, p.PaymentId });
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

The Staff/User model is as follows:

```
// Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Othernames { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Staff No")]
    public string StaffNo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Department")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Location")]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public string Photo { get; set; }

    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StaffComponent> Components { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

One of the major confusions is that it works in debug mode but when I run without debugging, it throws up the above error.

I will appreciate any effort to guide me in resolving this.

Comment: Instead of adding the staffcomponents directly to the table try adding the component to the staff object via the Components navigation property within the loop.  `staff.Components.Add(component)`  This will bypass the many-to-many table and create all that for you.

Comment: @Kevbo, You mean looping through each of the components adding it that way to the staff?

Comment: Yes.  You already have a list of the components so just add them to the components property of the staff object.  If you setup your db correctly you will have a list<component> in the staff object containing all the components. Just add your components to this and the SaveChanges will add the relationship row for you.

Comment: The same goes for removing the relationship...  `Staff.Components.Remove(comp);`

Comment: Please could you give more elaborate guide on this. I'm trying to add it but getting an intellisense error that "cannot convert from System.Collections.GEneric.IList<StaffComponent> to StaffComponent". Is there any suggestion on how to deal with that so I can forge ahead with the solution you proferred?

This is what I tried to do Staff.Components.Add(newComponents);

Comment: it sounds like your trying to add the staffcomponent object.  you dont need to reference this.  You want the Component object.  Get your list of component objects you want to associate to and add those directly to the Components property of the staff object